# Usage of the definite article "the" and its omission

Tags: definite-article

Is it mandatory to use **the** in the following sentence? If I omit **the** from the sentence, will that be correct and what difference in meaning will it create?

Here's the example:

- As a teacher, I feel disappointed for **(the) students** who could not pass last year's maths exam.

I know I can say "As a teacher, I feel disappointed for ***a*** **student** who could not pass last year's maths exam". So if I want to make it plural I think I should say like this way "As a teacher, I feel disappointed for **students** who could not pass last year's maths exam". Isn't it?

Note that when I am saying this, I have no particular students in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct, and commonly used, either with the definite article or without, as long as the noun is plural. As you state, an article *is* needed for a singular noun. Here are some correct examples.

> Ships are coming into port.
>
> The ships are coming into port.
>
> A ship is coming into port.

The following is *incorrect*.

> Ship is coming into port.

Confusingly, some nouns may not use an article in the singular, e.g.

> Go to school.
>
> He's in hospital. *Heard in UK more than in USA.*

Also, [non-count nouns](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-when-not-to-use-the-definite-article/) may omit an article.

> Pour milk into the flour.
>
> Pour the milk into the flour.
>
> Put flour on the breadboard.